# Cannot print cards in card game

Tags: java, object, printing, arraylist, playing-cards

I'm developing a java card game, which is close to the card game *hearts*. I have much of the structure, but now i'm stuck and i cannot get this to print. It has a variable amount of players and 
- I need it to deal out five cards to each player
- To show which cards each player has received.
I believe that there is a problem in the 'Session.dealHands'-method. Hope you guys can help.

***Session class***

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Session {

    // Variables
    static int numberOfPlayers = PlayGame.generateRandom(2, 10);
    Player player[] = new Player[numberOfPlayers];
    static int numberOfRounds;
    static int leadPlayer = 1;

    // Initializes the class Deck and assign it to DeckOfCards
    static Deck deckOfCards = new Deck();

    public static void initializeSession() {
        // initializes the deck from Deck class
        Deck.createDeck();
        // Creates an array of players
        Player player[] = new Player[numberOfPlayers];

        for (int i = 0; i < Session.numberOfPlayers; i++) {
            player[i] = new Player(i);
        }
        // Makes the possible amount of rounds determined by numberOfPlayers
    maxRounds();
    whoIsLeadPlayer();


        System.out.println("Welcome - The Game has Startet");
        System.out.println("\n" + "The number of Players " + numberOfPlayers);
        System.out.println("Number of rounds is: " + numberOfRounds);
        System.out.println("\n" + "The leadPlayer is: " + leadPlayer );

        //playSession(player);
    }
public static void whoIsLeadPlayer(){
    //for(leadPlayer = 1; leadPlayer < numberOfPlayers; leadPlayer++){
        //Player pls = new Player();

    //}


}

    private static void maxRounds() {
            if (numberOfPlayers == 2) {
                numberOfRounds = 5;
            } else if (numberOfPlayers == 3) {
                numberOfRounds = 3;
            } else if (numberOfPlayers < 6) {
                numberOfRounds = 2;
            } else {
                numberOfRounds = 1;
            }       
    }

    public static void playSession(Player player[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Session.numberOfRounds; i++) {

            dealHands(player);
            playRound(player);

        }
    }

    // Should be able to deal a Hand
    public static void dealHands(Player player[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        Card currentCard = deckOfCards.getCard(PlayGame.generateRandom(0, 52));
        player[i].hand.add(new Card(Card.rank, Card.suit));
        //System.out.println(player[i].hand);
    }



        /*for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            Card currentCard = deckOfCards.getCard(PlayGame.generateRandom(0, deckOfCards.cards.size()));
            player[i].hand.add(new Card(currentCard.getRank(), Card.getSuit()));
        }*/

    }

    public static void playRound(Player player[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Session.numberOfPlayers; i++) {
            playTurn(player);
        }
    }

    public static void playTurn(Player player[]) {
        // placeCard();
    }

    private static void placeCard() {

    }

    public static void printCards(Player player[]) {
        // Card card;
        for (int i = 0; i <= Session.numberOfPlayers; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= player[i].hand.size(); j++) {
                Card card = player[i].hand.get(j);
                System.out.println("player" + i + "card " + card.getSuit() + ""
                        + card.getRank());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Deck Class***

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Deck {
    // Create Arraylist to store deck of cards
    static ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

    // Adds numbers to the ArrayList
    public static void createDeck() {
        for (int suit = 0; suit < 3; suit++) {
            for (int rank = 0; rank < 12; rank++) {
                cards.add(new Card(suit, rank));
            }
        }
    }

    // Get Card Method to get a card from the Card class
    public Card getCard(int iD) {
        //Card card = ID;
        Card gC = new Card(Card.getRank(), Card.getSuit());
        cards.remove(iD);
        return gC;
    }
}
```

***Card Class***

```
import java.util.*;

public class Card {

    static int rank;
    static int suit;

    public static int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public void setRank(int rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public static int getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public void setSuit(int suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public Card(int rank, int suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }
}
```

***Player Class***

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Player {

    boolean leadPlayer;
    int score;
    ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>();

    // Getters and Setter methods to be implemented later
    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public int getPlayerID() {
        return playerID;
    }

    public void setPlayerID(int playerID) {
        playerID = 1;
        this.playerID = playerID;
    }

    public ArrayList<Card> getHand() {
        return hand;
    }

    public void setHand(ArrayList<Card> hand) {
        this.hand = hand;
    }

    public boolean isLeadPlayer() {
        return leadPlayer;
    }

    public void setLeadPlayer(boolean leadPlayer) {
        Session.leadPlayer++;
        this.leadPlayer = leadPlayer;
    }

    int playerID;

    // Constructor to call when using a Player
    public Player(int playerID) {
        this.playerID = playerID;
    }
}
```

***Main class***

```
import java.util.Random;

public class PlayGame {

    // Starts the program
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Session.initializeSession();

    }

    public static int generateRandom(int min, int max) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int random = r.nextInt(max - min) + min;
        return random;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), not your entire project.

Comment: You may also want to tell us just how your code is misbehaving. Are you getting exceptions thrown at you? Is every card the same (which I suspect to be the case)?

Answer (score 3):

Please get rid of those static methods and fields!

```
public class Card {

    static int rank; // ???????
    static int suit; // ???????

    public static int getRank() { // ???????
        return rank;
    }

    public void setRank(int rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public static int getSuit() { // ???????
        return suit;
    }
```

This makes no sense as no Card will have its own suit and rank field since they will be properties of the class not the instance. Make them all ***non-static*** instance fields and methods.

In fact likely nothing in your code above should be static except for the main method.

**Edit:**
Also, this needs to be changed:

```
player[i].hand.add(new Card(Card.rank, Card.suit));
```

You're trying to get the rank and suit of the ***class*** Card which doesn't really make logical sense. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: OK, but how should I then be able to implement them in Session class? it complains when i remove static. :)

Comment: @user1938165: you're fixing the wrong thing. It's not telling you to use static, it's saying that you can't access non-static fields in a static way. The solution is to not try to access them in a static way. Access them only through a Card instance (object), not through the Card class. See Edit to answer above.